# WPF C# Make ScrollBar Clickable Only

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview

I am creating an application which currently lets users scroll to zoom into an image. Currently, if I try to use a scrollview to allow users to scroll down the page, it breaks this feature. Is there any way for me to implement a scrollbar that does not access the scroll wheel? What I am looking for is a way to only allow users to access the scrollbar by clicking it, not by using the scrollwheel.

Comment: you mean you want to block scroll up or down?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI I want to include a scrollbar which allows the user to navigate up and down, but only by clicking rather than using the scroll wheel so that they can still use the scroll wheel for zooming into an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the MouseWheel event on your image and set e.Handled = true at the end.

Contrived example -

**XAML**:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Canvas Width="1000" Height="1000" Background="PeachPuff" MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**Code**:

```
    private void Canvas_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Canvas).Background = Brushes.Blue;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```